# How to change color in xml file?

Tags: java, android, xml

I built a simple menu (That if I click "menu" option in my emulator on eclipse I will see it), and I have three options in this menu: About us, preferences and exit. Everyone of them are work and good, but I have a small problem.
The color of the menu is white, and the text is white too so I cant to see the text.

This is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item 
        android:text="About Us"
        android:id="@+id/aboutUs"
        android:numericShortcut="1"
        android:alphabeticShortcut="a" />

    <item 
        android:text="Perferences"
        android:id="@+id/perferences" />

    <item 
        android:text="Exit"
        android:id="@+id/exit" />

</menu>
```

Hope for answers and thanks in advance!

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater blowUp = getMenuInflater();
        blowUp.inflate(R.menu.cool_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add:

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/any_color_you_want</item>
```

to your styles.xml

Comment: When I added this, its wrote me this:

Comment: that is used from api11 and above and my min is API8

Comment: "is only used in API11 and higher (current min is 8)"